# Does android support video cropping?

Tags: java, android

i need to implement crop operation over a Video,is there any builtin class or third party library available or is there any alternate approach. I already had a walkthrough from android developer to Mr.Google !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know android has no built in API's for those video manipulations. I recommend [FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#How-do-I-encode-single-pictures-into-movies_003f). Go through this [tutorial](http://www.mumuen.com/2012/03/crop-video-using-ffmpeg.html) once. I have used [xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler) with java swing. It served well and I think it might help you.

Comment: As an addition to @JJPA Have a look at https://github.com/tito/ffmpeg-android or http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/How%20to%20compile%20FFmpeg%20for%20Android maybe this will get you started

Comment: thanks for replying ! should i install NDK and does it requires c code.

Comment: @Blu Yes you need to have NDK. Take a look at QVDev's link.

Comment: @JJPA Sir ! i've found the below written command to crop a video.

ffmpeg –i input_video_file_name –vf crop=w:h:x:y output_file_name

Description [Note that w and h are width and height, and x, y is the position of the top-left corner before crop. vf means video filter. crop is kind of video filter in ffmpeg.] the width and height values seem to crop the video into a rectangular shape, is it feasible to crop the video in a circular shape ? your links are very useful !

Comment: Sir ! so far i've downlaoded the library, and trying to build it in windows with cygwin but i am unable to do so, now i'm trying with MINGW for windows.  I've few questions, 1) should i use linux machine instead. 2) is it feasible to crop the video in a circular shape. thanks !

Comment: 1) As a linux user I'm ok with that. Yes, you can use Linux. You can find a tutorials on that. 2) I'm not sure about feasibility about how difficult or easy is to crop a video in circular shape as I didn't do it. But do let me know about that. I used ffmpeg to do some silly things. Any way all the best for you on that. I'll try to find out things on that. If I find I'll let you know